Rewriting colnames into dates
Consider the following dataset:
mydata<-data.frame(id = c("R007", "R008"),
                   cohort = c(1,2),
                   maledummy = c(1,0),
                   employment_2016_12_01 = c(1,0), 
                   employment_2017_01_01 = c(1,1), 
                   employment_2017_02_01 =c(1,1))


In this dataset, I observe the individuals R007 and R008 (id-variable). From these individuals, I observe their gender (maledummy) as well as whether they worked in a particular month (employment_2016_12_01, …, employment_2017_02_01). Now I would like to rearrange the dataset to get to this final result:
#Final dataset
mydatafinal<-data.frame(id = c("R007", "R007", "R007",
                               "R008", "R008", "R008"),
                   cohort = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                   maledummy = c(1,1,1,0,0,0),
                   employment = c(1,1,1,0,0,0), 
                   date = c("2016-12-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01",
                              "2016-12-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01"))
mydatafinal$date<-as.Date(mydatafinal$date, "%Y-%m-%d")


In other words, I would like to use the ending of employment variable and change this into a date. In addition, the columns now become additional rows. Is there anyone who has an idea on how to do this?
I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

library(tidyverse)
mydata |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with("employment_"),
               names_to = "date",
               values_to = "employment") |>
  mutate(date = date %>% 
           str_remove("employment_") %>%
           ymd())

Result
  id    cohort maledummy date       employment
  <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl> <date>          <dbl>
1 R007       1         1 2016-12-01          1
2 R007       1         1 2017-01-01          1
3 R007       1         1 2017-02-01          1
4 R008       2         0 2016-12-01          0
5 R008       2         0 2017-01-01          1
6 R008       2         0 2017-02-01          1

